# How to display processes that are running of computer in LordPE?

Tags: pe

I tried to install some LordPE version but all when I open then no program that is  running displayed in LordPE.I don't know why?
[image]

I hope you guys show me the way to fix this problem.I appreciate all of your help?

Comment: LordPE is an ancient tool and hasn't been updated for recent versions of Windows

Comment: To add on to this, I'm not familiar with LordPE (although the name rings a bell) but you can use Process Monitor by Sysinternals depending on what your goals are. If that's not what you want then maybe if you clarified what you want access to we can give you an appropriate alternative tool.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Maybe there’s another way to achieve what you need instead of this tool.